# Proving $\sin((n+1)a)=2\cos a\sin(na)-\sin((n-1)a)$ and $\cos((n+1)a)=2\cos a\cos(na)-\cos((n-1)a)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have to prove the following Simpson formulas:

a) $\quad\sin((n+1)\alpha)=2\cos( \alpha)\sin(n \alpha)-\sin((n-1)\alpha)$

b) $\quad\cos((n+1)\alpha)=2\cos(\alpha)\cos(n \alpha)-\cos((n-1)\alpha)$

I am assuming that $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Can I know which identities I have to use and how?

Answer (score 1):

Using sum to product formula we have
cos(a)+cos(b)=2cos(a+b)/2 . cos(a-b)/2
a=(n+1)x    b=(n-1)x
cos(n+1)x + cos(n-1)x = 2cosnx.cosx

sin(a)+sin(b)=2sin(a+b)/2 . cos(a-b)/2

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the *addition formulæ* with $\cos(n+1)\alpha=\cos(n\alpha+\alpha)$, $\;\cos(n+1)\alpha=\cos(n\alpha-\alpha)$, and similarly for the sine.

Comment: For what? The general addition formulæ?

Answer (score 0):

After transposing you should use addition formulas for sines and cosines in order to obtain their products.